How to test a button click in Jest
I'm writing a website that has an interactive deck of cards. What I want to check is that when I click the deck-shuffle-btn the function shuffleDeck is run.
I've got my event listener in my script.js file :
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    document.getElementById("deck-shuffle-btn").addEventListener("click", () => shuffleDeck(deck.shuffledDeck));
});

I also have an object named deck that has the deck of cards in it, a function called deckShuffle() that re-arranges the order of the cards and a function called resetDeck() that returns everything back to default values before shuffling the cards once more.
So when this button is clicked, it should run deckShuffle() and shuffle the deck.
Then I've got my test in my script.test.js file:
describe("Test deckShuffle function when using the deck-shuffle-btn element", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        // sets a mock HTML site with a single button element in it
        document.body.innerHTML =
            '<div>' + +
            '<button id="deck-shuffle-btn"></button>' +
            '</div>';
        // reset the deck object
        resetDeck();
        // takes a copy of the deck to run tests against
        testElement = [...deck.shuffledDeck];
        // trigger a button click
        $("#deck-shuffle-btn").trigger("click");
    });
    test("shuffledDeck is not the same order as testElement, showing that the deck has been shuffled", () => {
        expect(deck.shuffledDeck).not.toEqual(testElement);
    });
})

This test fails, showing that the deck has not been shuffled when the button is clicked as I expected.
I suspect this is something to do with how I am implementing my test, rather than how I am implementing the event listener in my code.
EDIT - I updated the syntax as suggested by a comment, but this still is not working correctly.

jquery element selector by id should be used with # tag: $("#deck-shuffle-btn"). Also, you are calling shuffleDeck function when attaching an eventListener. Does your function return another function that is called upon clicking? Or is it a mistake and it should be something like .addEventListener("click", () => shuffleDeck(deck.shuffledDeck);)?
